# Why can't terminate a process if its threads are in unkown states?

Tags: thread-safety

From my experience, when main thread is ready to exit, it should wait until other threads normally exit.

But from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686722(v=VS.85).aspx, it looks when process is terminated, all related resources are freed, so if certain worker thread is doing heavy work, waiting may be a litter longer.  Can I ignore the waiting?

Also in the above link, I find

> Do not terminate a process unless its
>   threads are in **known states**. If a
>   thread is waiting on a kernel object,
>   it will not be terminated until the
>   wait has completed. This can cause the
>   application to hang.

This is too short to understand why killing a thread in unknown states when process exits is wrong.

can someone give me more detail about the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, when a thread is waiting on an object in the kernel, it will not exit until the waiting is over.

So, let's say you have an application with 3 threads, in the following states:

1. Main thread, currently idle
2. UI handling thread, currently idle
3. A thread waiting on a kernel object

If you kill the process, thread 2 will die, making the UI input handlers die, and therefore giving the appearance that the application is unresponsive (hung). Until thread #3 finishes waiting on the kernel, the main thread won't exit, and so the process remains running, and the process resources don't get released.

So, I think it's basically saying that it's better to ask a process to exit normally, instead of sending it a kill signal, because you can get yourself into a situation like the one described if any of the process threads are waiting on kernel objects.